# draw gps point as a line in iphone

Tags: iphone, gps, draw

i want to create and iphone application that include a section similar to NIKE+ app. i need to draw the collection of GPS points. 
any one have any idea,

note: i don't want to draw these point on the map

regards

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to draw on a map you could probably just create a custom UIView and draw using Quartz 2D. Having said this, if you are going to be redrawing regularly you're going to need to look at optimisations like only redrawing certain areas or caching the CGContextRef. [Apple's Quartz documentation explains it all pretty well.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)